# ¿Cómo obtengo un registro que no existe?

Tags: mysql

Estoy realizando la base de datos de un Learning Management System, pero me he estancado en una parte.

```
CREATE TABLE estudiante(
  idestudiante INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idpersona INT,
  idcarrera INT,
  fechadenacimiento DATE,
  telefono VARCHAR(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (idpersona) REFERENCES persona (idpersona),
  FOREIGN KEY (idcarrera) REFERENCES carrera (idcarrera)
);

CREATE TABLE actividad(
  idactividad INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idtema INT,
  ponderacion INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(100),
  instrucciones TEXT,
  fechadeentrega DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idtema) REFERENCES tema (idtema)
);
CREATE TABLE entrega(
  identrega INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idestudiante INT,
  idactividad INT,
  archivo BLOB,
  fechadeentrega DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idestudiante) REFERENCES estudiante (idestudiante),
  FOREIGN KEY (idactividad) REFERENCES actividad (idactividad)
);
```

Quisiera tener una consulta que me muestre las actividades que un estudiante entrego y no entrego, pero únicamente he logrado mostrar las entregadas y quisiera que también me mostrará las entregas inexistentes.
/*Registros*/

```
    INSERT INTO actividad VALUES (1, 1,50, 'Mapa mental', 'Realiza un mapa mental.',  '2021-06-30');
    INSERT INTO actividad VALUES (2, 1,30, 'Mapa conceptual', 'Realiza un mapa conceptual.',  '2021-06-30');
    INSERT INTO actividad VALUES (3, 1,10, 'Cuadro sinóptico', 'Realiza un cuadro sinóptico.', '2021-06-30');
    INSERT INTO actividad VALUES (4, 1,10, 'Cuadro comparativo', 'Realiza un cuadro comparativo.', '2021-06-30');
INSERT INTO actividad VALUES (5, 2, 100,'Linea del tiempo', 'Realiza una linea del tiempo.',  '2021-06-30');

INSERT INTO entrega VALUES (1, 1, 1, NULL, '2021-06-29');
INSERT INTO entrega VALUES (2, 1, 2, NULL, '2021-06-29');
INSERT INTO entrega VALUES (3, 1, 3, NULL, '2021-06-29');
INSERT INTO entrega VALUES (4, 1, 4, NULL, '2021-06-30');
```

/*Obtiene las actividades entregadas de un tema en particular de cualquier estudiante.*/

```
SELECT actividad.nombre AS 'Actividad', IF(actividad.fechadeentrega > entrega.fechadeentrega, 'Entregada', 'Entregada con retraso') AS 'Estado' FROM estudiante
INNER JOIN entrega ON estudiante.idestudiante = entrega.idestudiante INNER JOIN actividad ON entrega.idactividad = actividad.idactividad INNER JOIN tema ON
actividad.idtema = tema.idtema WHERE tema.idtema = 1 AND estudiante.idestudiante = 1;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: investiga sobre left join y rigth join...

Comment: Ya intente con LEFT JOIN y RIGHT JOIN pero como la tabla es muchos a muchos creo que hace que cambie el procedimiento.

Comment: Cuales tablas son muchos a muchos? que intentaste con left y right join?

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar un INNER JOIN esperas que las tablas tengan datos en todas las claves por las que unes las tablas, entendiendo que si no hay datos, por ejemplo en actividad, no te interesa mostrarlo.

Si lo que quieres es mostrar los datos de estudiantes que no tienen actividad puedes recurrir a realizar un `LEFT JOIN` con lo que mostrará también las filas donde no existan entregas o actividades, aunque con datos a `NULL`.

```
SELECT actividad.nombre AS 'Actividad', 'No entregada' AS 'Estado' 
FROM estudiante
LEFT JOIN entrega ON estudiante.idestudiante = entrega.idestudiante 
LEFT JOIN actividad ON entrega.idactividad = actividad.idactividad 
LEFT JOIN tema ON actividad.idtema = tema.idtema 
WHERE tema.idtema is null AND estudiante.idestudiante = 1;
```